# How Can I execute a PHP function inside a Script tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have as function for my css that looks like this

```
function include_css($css="") {
include(SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes'.DS.'stylesheets'.DS.$css);
}
```

And in the header I use this to call it

```
<style type="text/css"><?php include_css('public.css'); ?></style>
```

I would like to do a similar function to call a javascript file to load in ckeditor

```
function include_javascript($js="") {
include(SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes'.DS.'ckeditor'.DS.$js);
}
```

But this bit of code doesn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript"><?php include_javascript('ckeditor.js'); ?></script>
```

The tool bar doesn't show up when doing it this way.  It will show up when I use the website.

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Why doesn't this work the same way as the Style tag?  Since this doesn't work is there a similar way to put PHP into a Script tag?

Comment: Depends what the include includes...

Comment: Do you try to display content of these files?? For what? 
You can display link for these files and browser will load it.

Comment: HOW does it fail? What do you see inside the <script> tag?

Answer (score 0):

I put php code inside of script tags frequently for instance to set the initial value of a javascript variable. There is no particular issue with inserting php tags inside of a script tag.

Normally you would load javascript separately to speed page load like this:

```
<script src="/path-to_js/js-file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So something like this should work:

```
function include_javascript($js="") {
    if ($js)
        echo "<script src=\"/js-path/$js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>";
}
```

If you are trying to embed the javascript code into your html what you are doing ought to work. I noticed that you are setting a default value for your parameter. Make sure that something is actually passed and that the file actually exists. If the result is

```
<script></script>
```

then one of these is most likely the problem.